# How do you crop all images in 1 folder?

Tags: java

I have a project that I need to crop all the images in my folder. So far it does crop and erases the extra white space around it, however, I need to put the exact file name on the file path. I have attached the code below to show you what my code does. So in short I need help making my code crop a whole folder of images instead of just 1. And then automatically saving the cropped image in another folder.
Thank you.

```
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

public class code {
    private BufferedImage img;
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        code trim = new code(new File("D:\\eclipse-java-workspace\\image_manipulation\\sample_input_images\\DP936BA.jpg"));
        System.out.println("Starting first image..");
        trim.trim();
        trim.write(new File("D:\\eclipse-java-workspace\\image_manipulation\\sample_out_images\\output5.jpg"));
    
    }
      
    public code(File input) {
        try {
            img = ImageIO.read(input);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException( "Problem reading image", e );
        }
    }

    public void trim()
    {
        System.out.println(getTrimmedHeight2());
        BufferedImage img2 = img.getSubimage(getTrimmedWidth2(), getTrimmedHeight2(), getTrimmedWidth()-getTrimmedWidth2(), getTrimmedHeight()-getTrimmedHeight2());
        BufferedImage copyOfImage = new BufferedImage(img2.getWidth(), img2.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
        Graphics g = copyOfImage.createGraphics();
        g.drawImage(img2, 0, 0, null);

        img = copyOfImage;
    }
    private int getTrimmedWidth2() {
        int height = this.img.getHeight();
        int width  = this.img.getWidth();
        int lowest = 99999;

        for(int i = 0; i < height; i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j < width-1; j++) {
                if(img.getRGB(j, i) != Color.WHITE.getRGB() ) {


                    if(j<lowest)
                    {

                        lowest = j;
                    }

                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        return lowest;
    }
    public void write(File f) {
        try {
            ImageIO.write(img, "jpg", f);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException( "Problem writing image", e );
        }
    }

    private int getTrimmedWidth() {
        int height = this.img.getHeight();
        int width  = this.img.getWidth();
        int trimmedWidth = 0;

        for(int i = 0; i < height; i++) {
            for(int j = width - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
                if(img.getRGB(j, i) != Color.WHITE.getRGB() &&
                        j > trimmedWidth) {
                    trimmedWidth = j;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        return trimmedWidth ;

    }

    private int getTrimmedHeight() {
        int width = this.img.getWidth();
        int height = this.img.getHeight();
        int trimmedHeight = 0;

        for(int i = 0; i < width; i++) {
            for(int j = height - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
                if(img.getRGB(i, j) != Color.WHITE.getRGB() &&
                        j > trimmedHeight) {
                    trimmedHeight = j;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        return trimmedHeight;
    }

    private int getTrimmedHeight2() {
        int width = this.img.getWidth();
        int height = this.img.getHeight();
        int lowest = 99999;

        for(int i = 0; i < width; i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j < height-1; j++) {
                if(img.getRGB(i, j) != Color.WHITE.getRGB() ) {

                    if(j<lowest)
                    {
                        System.out.println(j);
                        lowest = j;
                    }

                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        return lowest;
    }


}
```

Comment: First get a list of files `File[] fileList = directory.listFiles()`, then use a loop to go through the list and create a `code` object for each file and trim it `for (int i = 0; i < fileList.length; i++) {code trim = new code(fileList[i]); trim.trim(); trim.write(...yourNewPath);}` You should also check that the files in the `fileList` are not directories, and that they are images before you attempt to trim them, otherwise you will have errors.

Comment: so I would have to list all the files? Because the folder consists of hundreds of images. Sorry I just started learning java 3 weeks ago.

Comment: No, you don't list any of them. You only need to folder path, then you can get a list of all the files like so `File[] fileList = new File("D:/your/directory/path/).listFiles();`

Comment: Where exactly does that line of code go? I'm really having a hard time with this. Thank you for helping me

Answer (score -1):

You can do this by using a folder path to get a list of files `File[] fileList = directory.listFiles()`, then use a loop to go through the list and create a code object for each file and trim it `for (int i = 0; i < fileList.length; i++) {...}`.

Below is an example of how this might work. I have added comments explaining the steps. Beware that I have not tested the code, but it should work:

```
//Path to your folder
final static String folderPath = "D:/your/directory/path/";

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    //Get a list of all files in the folder
    File[] fileList = new File(folderPath).listFiles();

    System.out.println("Starting first image..");

    //Loop through the above list of files
    for (int i = 0; i < fileList.length; i++){
        //For each file create a new code object and trim it
        code trim = new code(fileList[i]);
        trim.trim();

        //Create a file path to save the trimmed file with the same name but add "_TRIMMED" to the end
        //You will need to alter this line to put the file extension in the correct place
        String newFileName = getPath() + "/" + fileList[i].getName() + "_TRIMMED"; 

        //Finally save the updated file to the new path           
        trim.write(new File(newFileName));
    }    

    System.out.println("All images trimmed..");
}
```

You should also check that the files in the `fileList` are not folders, and that they are images before you attempt to trim them, rather than just throwing a RuntimeException and stopping the whole application. But I will leave that part up to you.

Comment: It's not doing anything. Unless I probably didn't do it right still.

Comment: @jigz Step through the code with a debugger, or add `println` statements so that you can see what the code is doing and if the `fileList ` actually contains any files `System.out.println("Found "+fileList.length + " files to trim.");`. Also, double-check that the `folderPath` is pointing to a folder with files in it.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply but I finally figured out what you were saying, thank you so much!